# Switching between multiple java versions

Tags: java, macos, osx-yosemite

OS : OSX Yosemite

I use [jEnv](https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv) to switch between java versions.

```
Asiris-Mac-Book-Pro:~ Asiri$ jenv global 1.6 

Asiris-Mac-Book-Pro:~ Asiri$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)


Asiris-Mac-Book-Pro:~ Asiri$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home

Asiris-Mac-Book-Pro:~ Asiri$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    1.7.0_67, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.5.0_30-b03, x86_64:   "J2SE 5.0"  /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.5.0/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Why is this happening?

This configuration till seems to use the java 1.7.

How to correctly switch to java 1.6?

Answer (score 0):

`Java Runtime Environmen (JRE)` is not the same thing as `Java Development Kit (JDK)`.

**You are** running `JRE 1.6`

It's unclear what you're trying to do; more information on what the scope of your project involves might have been helpful - so to answer your question(s):

> 1. It's happening because you've gotten the two Java distributions confused
> 2. Version 1.7 is the Java Development Kit
> 3. You're using Java Runtime Environment 1.6 as your default

Comment: I want to use java 1.6 to use for a project. 1.6 jdk. How to do it

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi, I don't use `jEnv`, since it's easy enough to add a line to `~/.bash_profile` that'll do the same thing. If you wanted to use `1.6` as the default then you could add this export: `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6\``. Also this command will show the help:  `/usr/libexec/java_home -h`

Comment: jEnv lets to set it up locally for a directory that' why I wanted to use it. Thanks for the help. I'll try that.